Is it possible to keep the state of the Jetpack Navigation (NavHost) after the screen rotation which leads to activity restart?
Main issue is that I want my app to show the same screen it was showing before and after screen rotation. I want the NavHostController backstack to stay the same too.
I have an Android application built with Compose and Jetpack NavHostController. The MainActivity code is like this:
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: OurViewModel

    @Inject
    lateinit var ourViewModelFactory: OurViewModelFactory

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create()
        appComponent.inject(this)
        ourViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this, ourViewModelFactory).get(OurViewModel::class.java)

        setContent {
            OurTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                ThisScreenNavigation(navController, viewModel)
                navController.navigate(MAIN_PAGE)
            }
        }
    }
}

ThisScreenNavigatiion Code:
@Composable
 fun ThisScreenNavigation(navController: NavHostController, 
   viewModel : OurViewModel) {

NavHost(navController, startDestination = MAIN_PAGE) {
    composable(route  = MAIN_PAGE)
    {
        MainPage(navController, viewModel)
    }

    composable(route = SECOND_PAGE)
    {
        SecondPage(navController, viewModel)
    }
}

}
So, using Dagger, the Viewmodel instance survives after screen rotation.
But the navController is reset every time the screen is rotated.
I tried to save the state of the navcontroller when screen is rotated and then restore it as the bundle after activity is re-created but it did not work:
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    val navState = savedInstanceState.getBundle("NavKey")
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    if(navState != null){
    navController.restoreState(navState)

    .....
    }
    }

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {
  val navState = navController.saveState()
    outState.putBundle("NavKey", navState)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
}

But it didn't work. What is the correct way?

it's not possible because behind the seen rememberNavController used rememberSaveable and it's survived the orientation changes. can you please share the code of ThisScreenNavigation?

The latest versions of the compose navigation library restore the back stack itself. So try upgrading your compose navigation version to the latest stable version

you call navController.navigate(MAIN_PAGE) during composition, you should call such calls in callbacks
setContent {
    OurTheme {
        val navController = rememberNavController(). 
        ThisScreenNavigation(navController, viewModel)
        //navController.navigate(MAIN_PAGE) <- remove this line
    }
}

here you can find more information about phases

Thanks but this didn't work.
